# lyx bibliography does not display math symbols

Tags: symbols, lyx

I am using the `IEEEtran` template.
I have to cite one reference, this reference has several special math characters,
when I tried to convert it to pdf file, LyX gave many errors about it,

Errors:
six "*undefined control sequence.*"

```
Description:
...ncertainty measures for {$\ell^{2}(\mathbb
                                             {R}^{n})$},
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

From the error and description, it should be the title, 
and the title of reference is :

```
title="Entropy-Based Uncertainty Measures for {$\ell^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$},
{$\ell^{2}(\mathbb{Z})$}, and {$\ell^{2}(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})$}
with a Hirschman Optimal transform for {$\ell^{2}(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})$}"
```

However, when I  add one special relation symbol `\triangleq` or  complicated binary operators, similar symbols in the body of the LyX file anywhere (not Greek letters),   LyX can convert into pdf file smoothly, but leave unwanted symbols in the pdf file.

I don't have anything in the preamble. and the bibliography works with the same author with different paper title, so it is not a problem with the author name but with the math symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load the `amssymb` package.

(In LyX: choose "document"-->"settings"--> "latex preamble" , copy \usepackage{amssymb} into the empty region on the right side, press "apply" and "close")

Comment: Thanks, I added \usepackage{amssymb}  in the preamble, but it still does not work

Comment: sorry, I rebooted my computer, added \usepackage{amssymb} back in the preamble, it works. Thank you so much !

Comment: From menu, choose "document"-->"settings"--> "latex preamble" , copy  \usepackage{amssymb} into the empty region on the right side, press "apply" and "close", done!